# A Flutter TextField and Google Indic Keyboard related problem

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, indic

I am new to `Flutter` and am building an app that supports `Malayalam` language. I test the `TextField` Malayalam entry using Google Indic Keyboard. The TextField is set to take `textInputAction` as newline. While the action works fine in English, the newline does not work when I switch to `Malayalam`.

```
TextField(
  controller: _postController,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
  maxLength: 16384,
  maxLines: 10,
  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: 'Write something here...',
  ),
)
```

I could not find any setting in the **Indic Keyboard** that could fix it.
Most of my users prefer **Google Indic Keyboard**. I am stuck and the very purpose of the app is defeated!
Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting keyboardType as TextInputType.multiline

```
TextField(
  controller: _postController,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
  maxLength: 16384,
  maxLines: 10,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
    hintText: 'Write something here...',
  ),
)
```

Comment: That worked. You saved my day. Wonder why it works with English though.

Comment: Make sure you add `keyboardType` in all multiline fields.